# How are two photons entangled in the Xanadu computer?

Tags: photonics, optical-quantum-computing, continuous-variable, quantum-optics, linear-optics

I was recently reading about how [Xanadu](https://xanadu.ai/hardware) made a scalable, room-temperature-operating quantum computer using photons as qubits (see [this link](https://xanadu.ai/hardware)). It said that in the logic gates, it entangles two photons at some point, and in the video it just looks like two fiber-optic cables brought really close together with photons going through them. Could somebody please go more in-depth about how that works? I'm also having trouble understanding quantum logic gates (I understand classical ones though) so if somebody here would explain those that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Xanadu uses a CV (continous variable) model. Check their [introduction and comparison with usual quantum computing here](https://strawberryfields.ai/photonics/concepts/photonics.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QML researcher at Xanadu here.

Our X-series chip produce entangled states by squeezing light and then combining it at beam splitters: those 'cables' are waveguides in a chip, which when they are close enough they allow tunnelling between them and effectively couple those two modes.

Note that the squeezing is necessary in this case (for example, had we used laser light, which is coherent, the beam splitters would 'mix' it but without producing any entanglement).

Comment: Do you happen to have code that shows the process. I know Xanadu has software packages to simulate all this, but between Pennyland, Strawberry fields,...an outsider can easily get confused as to what's what...

Comment: yes of course: here is the website of strawberryfields which is our state of the art simulator for photonic circuits: https://strawberryfields.ai
you can find theory sections, live examples and code